# UISlider change value for online track playing

Tags: ios, uislider

As always after a lot of searching I back here to get help

my app playing sounds from url, I track the sound playing in uislider by update slider value when start the streamer playing

```
progressUpdateTimer =
    [NSTimer
     scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1
     target:self
     selector:@selector(updateProgress:)
     userInfo:nil
     repeats:YES];

- (void)updateProgress:(NSTimer *)updatedTimer
{
[progressView setValue: progress / duration];
}
```

this is my action for change slider value ( forward / backward the track)

```
- (IBAction)sliderMoved:(UISlider *)aSlider
{

    if (streamer.duration)
    {
       double newSeekTime = (aSlider.value) * streamer.duration;

      [streamer seekToTime:newSeekTime];
    }
}
```

What I want is when the user change the slider the value updates instantly without late of loading .. I mean change the slider value then load the sound
But what happened is by dragging the slider thumb to x position , it backs to its position and then move to x when sound loaded

How can I do that ? any help will be appreciated

Comment: hmm. If your having trouble with a `uislider` changing the duration. Then have you tried stopping the track, setting the duration and then replaying the tract at the set duration within the `slidermoved` statement?

Comment: this a good idea but ... I stop the updating of the progress when slider change and then re-back the progress updating again

Comment: Well have you tried a taking a look at this site because it clearly shows how to update a players duration with a uislider. http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2010/06/10/iphone-add-an-uislider-for-avaudioplayer/